# How to safely delete data in old M/S datastore of Google App Engine, for an aliased app?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app which was facing recurring server errors when on M/S datastore and have since migrated to HR datastore. The old application was aliased to redirect users to the new app and all is well for the new app and my users.

Now, I am trying to delete the old data in the M/S datastore, so that I can disable billing for the old application, but finding it difficult due to the following reasons :

- The **Datastore Admin** cannot be enabled because the application has been aliased.
- The **Datastore Viewer** throws up Server Errors -- possibly because

  - the viewer page is trying to load the list of all entities in the database and fails in the process because of the large number of entities in my app (the app is a meta-data driven multi-tenant online database application, with entities added dynamically and hence has more entities than the typical Google App Engine application) (or)
  - due to the unreliable M/S datastore (or)
  - a combination of both (or)
  - other issues
- The **remote_api** is not working out because the request is likely redirected to the new application.

I have already removed almost all composite indexes and vacuumed them to reduce the size to an extent. Most of the current usage is for built-in indexes, as shown in the latest Datastore statistics below :

```
                Entities      Built-in Indexes   Composite Indexes   Total
Total Size:     189 MBytes    1 GByte            3 MBytes            1 GByte
Entry Count:    203,793       9,506,340          20,797
```

The total storage used is around 1.27 GB and I can safely assume the entity which is taking up most of the storage. If I am able to delete records from those couple of entities, my datastore will fall within the 1 GB free quota.

```
Resource                 Usage         Billable    Price                 Cost
Datastore Stored Data    1.27 GBytes   0.27        $0.008/ GByte-day     $0.01
```

I do not want to fully delete the old-application as I have users already mapping the application to their Google Apps domain and the alias to the new application helps.

Would like to hear suggestions on how I can possibly delete the data from this old M/S datastore, of my now aliased application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to disable the application (and billing) without deleting your data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not sure if I could disable billing because my _Datastore Stored Data_ was a little over the free quota limits and hence I was looking for ways to delete the data first. Is it okay if I disable billing as-is?